# Is it possible to send GCM push notifications from app to app?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I've Google'd and can't seem to find a clear answer on this.

Using Cordova, is there a way I can let a user send a push notification to another user, from within the app?

All examples of GCM and Cordova I find are using a separate Web app to send the push notification.

I'd like a user to send a notification to another user in their "friends" list.

Answer (score 2):

You *theoretically* could allow users to **directly** (without any third party server in the middle) send GCM push notifications to each other as you just need to make [a HTTP POST request to the GCM service](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table1) in order to send a push notification. This is both bad and hard for a few reasons:

- You would need expose your GCM API key by baking it into the app. This would effectively allow anyone to send a push notification to any person with your app installed.
- Each app would have to locally keep track of the GCM token IDs of each of the app user's friends.

A better design would be to have a backend server that takes requests and sends the push notifications. Your app would then contact this server to request a message be sent to a certain person. The server can then look up the token for the person and send the push notification.

Comment: I fully understand that a middle-man server should be used, that's not really my question, but thank you for the clarification! What I want to know is, how would a user, inside the Cordova app, send a push notification? All examples I have read, show the use of a web-based app (not a Cordvoa mobile app) to send a message to the 3rd party server.

Comment: you just have to do an ajax post to the GCM, but as @Sam said, it's not a good idea

Comment: Well how would I normally send a push notification from say, a PHP app to all my users? If there is a 3rd party server, could I send an AJAX request to a custom API that would then send a push notification to a user?

Comment: @MrPablo Have a look at the link in my answer, you just send a HTTP POST request to Google's servers to send a push notification.

Comment: So, to sum up, for a user to send a notification to another user, from within a cordova app, I'd make a call to my own server, which would pass on the message? Basically, user to user gcm is a no go?

Comment: You *could* theoretically send a notification `user #1 -> google servers -> user #2` but this would be hard and bad as I outlined in my answer. A better method would indeed be `user #1 -> your backend -> google server -> user #2`.